# Translate controller action_name in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, renderpartial, rails-i18n

I want to translate my applications' views and as I'm using partial to render headers for each view like this:

`<%=t "#{controller.controller_name.capitalize} #{controller.action_name}" %>`

...I got stucked on translating them. How do I translate `controller.action_name` in custom translation file?

I've tried to access action names like this:

```
  parkings:
    index: "Parkings index"
    new: "New %{model}"
```

And many different variations of it, but every one failed. Could you help me?

This is a fragment of my controller:

```
  def new
    @parking = Parking.new
  end

  def create
    @parking = Parking.new(parking_params)

    if @parking.save
      redirect_to @parking, notice: t(:parking_created)
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have the translations in your locale file. Add an underscore or hyphen to separate words in the key

eg:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  parkings_index: Parkings index
  parkings_new: Parkings new page
```

view file

```
<%=t "#{controller_name}_#{action_name}" %>
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I've marked this answer as correct, now I only have to add translations to my locales but it finally worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you say `#{controller.controller_name}` it means that you have an object called `controller` accessible from your view, which is not true. Even if you manage to access the controller and the name of its action I don't think it's worth the effort and time.

Instead, you can structure your translation file somehow like this:

```
views:
  model_name (parkings): "Parkings"
    action_1_name (index): "Parkings Index"
    action_2_name (new): "New Parking"
    ...
```

and in your view say *(for example)* `<%= link_to (t "views.model_name.action_name"), :action %>`